# Sorting generic data structure array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics, interface

I have a generic class that contains an array. That array can be any data type(Double,Integer,String...) and I am trying to learn how could I sort this array just after constructed. I've wrote a sorting method for sorting the array after constructed. But, java inhibits sorting generic array with mysort method due to mismatch.

```
public class SortingTest<E> {

    private E[] array;
    //constructor which creates an object and sorts its array via mysort method.
    public SortingTest(E[] N){
        this.array = N;
        mysort(this.array);
    }
    //sorts array.
    private static<T extends Comparable<T>> void mysort(T[] arr){
        T temp = null;
        //Bubble sort increasing order.
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
            for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
                if(arr[i-1].compareTo(arr[i]) > 0 ){
                    temp = arr[i-1];
                    arr[i-1] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about what you are passing to `mysort(..)` in your constructor. What type is it? Does it match the bounds set by the method.

Comment: It can be any type as I said. The problem , which arise from didn't known implementation of Comparable interface, is solved by @Luiggi Mendoza Thank you very much for help.

Comment: As an aside, note that generics and arrays don't play well together.  You'll have a much better time working with `List`s and the rest of the Collections Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysort` method requires generic element `T` implements `Comparable<T>`, but generic `E` doesn't declare that implements `Comparable<E>`. Change the declaration to:

```
public class SortingTest<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you did "E extends Comparable<? super E>" to cover the case where the parent class implements Comparable.  Sorry if that's nit-picky.

Comment: What is the difference between them? Does using super keyword make any advantages?
@pscuderi

Comment: @Sixie it means that if the generic class `E` extends from another class `SE` and `SE` is the class that implements `Comparator<SE>`, then `E` won't need to implement `Comparator<E>` itself because already implements `Comparator<SE>`.